# Extra gap above div in list element when overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside of a list element. For some reason, the div is not on the same line as the list style bullet when overflow is hidden on the div. Any thoughts?

HTML:

```
<ul><li><div>Here is some long text</div></li></ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {width:150px;}
li {list-style-type:square}
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scottchantry/supcsayt/

Comment: Not sure why that's happening. does it have to be in a div? Works fine without that https://jsfiddle.net/supcsayt/1/

Answer (score 0):

The div is a block element, which makes it take up a new line. Adding `display:inline` to your div should do the trick. https://jsfiddle.net/supcsayt/2/

```
div {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: If I do that, then my overflow:hidden no longer works.

Comment: You could do something like ``margin-top: -18px`` on the div and keep it a block element, but it probably wouldn't be the best practice.